# How do I remove similar tuples in python as in (x,y) and (y,x)

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples [(1,2),(2,1),(4,4)] I want to remove either of these tuples where (a,b) = (b,a). ie.. (1,2) or (2,1)

Comment: There are several ways. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order of the elements in tuple doesn't matter, one way is to do:

```
In [11]: l = [(1,2), (2,1), (4,4)] 

In [12]: list(set([(x[0], x[1]) if x [0] < x[1] else (x[1], x[0]) for x in l]))
Out[12]: [(1, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Edit (A simpler version):

```
In [15]: list(set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in l))
Out[15]: [(1, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Instead of `(x[0], x[1]) if x [0] < x[1] else (x[1], x[0])`, why not `tuple(sorted(x))`? You don't need a list comprehension either; you can just remove the brackets and send a generator to `set`.